# Firebase Error - "Cannot parse Firebase URL" only in web

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing an issue with my Firebase setup that only occurs in the web environment. When I try to access my Firebase database, I encounter the following error:

`FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase URL. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com`

This error does not occur in my mobile app, and everything works fine there. I've double-checked the Firebase URL, and it seems to be correct. Here are some details about my setup:

- I'm using Firebase Realtime Database.
- The Firebase SDK version is [insert version number].
- The error occurs only in the web environment, specifically when running my application on [insert browsers and versions].

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and could you please guide me on how to resolve it? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me fix this problem. Thank you in advance!